# hello world jsp error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to reproduce the example from the JSP tutorial:

http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp

I have entered the code

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

    <%
    // This is a scriptlet.  Notice that the "date"
    // variable we declare here is available in the
    // embedded expression later on.
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    %>
Hello!  The time is now `<%= date %>`
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and saved it both as hello.jsp and index.jsp.

However all I get is Hello World, but not the date from the JAVA part.

The WEB server logs do not indicate any errors. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

It is important to recognize that whatever is in between

```
<%=  %>
```

can only be a printable token, such as string, int long etc...

and whatever is between

```
<% %>
```

is ordinary java code.

THerefore, simply change your code to:

```
 <%= date.toString() %>
```

and it should work, since it is a string that you are printing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `<%= new java.util.Date() %>` to print to your web page, use jsp expression which is `<%= %>` to print stuff to the browser. Jsp expression will convert anything to string for you. Note no semicolon